# How to call child AngularJs function within Iframe from Javascript parent?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, xforms

I am using a Javascript application in my application I need to load an AngularJS page in an IFrame. When I perform any button action on My Parent Javascript page, I need to call function from the child AngularJS page.

How to achieve this.

I have tried with `angular.getElement` but "angular" is `undefined` as its not used in my Javascript page.

With `document.getElementById` I am only able to get the IFrame but not able to call the function.

```
k=document.getElementById("qacceptframe")
```

I want to call the save/update function from the Controller of th AngularJS child Page when I click button on my Parent Javascript page.

Comment: You will have to set up event listeners in the angular app and in the parent application. check this https://gist.github.com/pbojinov/8965299

Comment: Script access to a frame's content is subject to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Scripts cannot access most properties in other window objects if the script was loaded from a different origin, including scripts inside a frame accessing the frame's parent.[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: Do you control the code in the angular app ? Is it same origin or not?